# Issues playing one certain DVD

Tags: video, dvd, dvd-backup

I have 2 home made DVD that a friend gave me. It has videos she has rights to redistribute for a Church ministry. And I am not sure, but I think they might be using one of those stand alone DVD copiers you see in magazines in order to make copies really fast(ish). The DVD is named "DVD_VIDEO_RECORDER" and the only file that I see is called "VIDEO_TS" and shows as unknown filetype, and 0 bytes in size. This DVD plays fine in my XBOX 360, and this Linux computer can play other DVD's fine, restricted or otherwise, but for some reason the DVD's she is giving me won't do anything with any of my video players, nor with Handbrake.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?? I have 2 DVD's with non-copy righted videos on them and I would really like to back them up for personal use. But can't seem to figure this out.

Here is the only messages VLC shows me. I will try to talk to my friend soon to ask what she uses to make these copies. There was one DVD she gave me that worked fine and normal. I was able to backup with handbrake no issues. So something must have changed on her end.

[image]

Comment: [VLC](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/vlc) is supposed to play everything that you throw at it. Have you tried that? If that works, you can also convert it to a more common format.

Comment: Yes, and VLC is my default on everything, even my Android devices. But here it gives me this messages "Playback failure:
DVDRead could not open the disc "/media/daniel/DVD_VIDEO_RECORDER".
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'dvd:///media/daniel/DVD_VIDEO_RECORDER'. Check the log for details." If I knew where VLC's logs were I would try to include them.

Comment: Press CTRL+M for messages.

Answer (score 0):

Can you play DVD movies (like those disks from a kiosk) in your system? If no, then you will probably need to install `libdvdread` and `libdvdcss`:

*libdvdread* provides the functionality that is required to access many DVDs. It parses IFO files, reads NAV-blocks, and performs CSS authentication and descrambling.

*libdvdread* probes for *libdvdcss* at runtime and if found, will use it to decrypt sections of the DVD as necessary

*libdvdcss* or libdvdcss2 is a free and open source software library for accessing and unscrambling DVDs encrypted with the Content Scramble System (CSS).

In terminal run:

`sudo apt-get install libdvdread4`

`sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh`

`sudo apt-get install libdvdcss2`

Comment: I've done that prior to trying this disk. And though I can't seem to find any Disney DVD's round here to test with as I've heard they have the most problems. But the movie "King Kong" plays fine, as well as the one of the season disks of Eureka. I have also tested in more than one DVD drive as I have 2 with this computer (one is an 10 plus year old Compaq from my first ever computer) and neither has any luck with this weird one, but play all other dvd's fine.

Again, the disk does have videos on it, as it plays in a DVD player fine. Just a weird 80's style menu. Almost looks like a BIOS.

Comment: Side note, don't you have to install libdvdcss2 first before running that install-css.sh things? It helped the install-css2 do the various processes it needed to?